# Do discrete embeddings of surface groups not necessarily carry an embedding of SL_2?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, lattices

We can get arithmetic lattices isomorphic to free groups in $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$, so in general we can’t expect homomorphisms of lattices into semisimple Lie groups to say much about $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$, even if we require the image to be discrete. In particular, unlike in higher-rank cases, such homomorphisms won’t necessarily extend to homomorphisms of $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$.

However, if $\Gamma<\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$ is cocompact and we have an discrete embedding (by which I mean a map which is both a homeomorphism and an isomorphism onto its image) of $\Gamma$ into some semisimple Lie group $G$, will we not necessarily get a copy of $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$ in $G$ containing (the image of) $\Gamma$?

By the considerations above, the image of $\Gamma$ in such a copy of $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$ might not look like it originally did (meaning the embedding of $\Gamma$ hasn’t necessarily extended to all of $\mathrm{SL}_2\mathbb{R}$), but part of me imagines that the image of $\Gamma$ should still determine something. Is this naïve?

Comment: Homomorphisms of a surface group into a lie group $G$ form a nice space, the character variety (with $2g$ coordinates in $G$ and one equation). The ones whose image lands in a copy of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ are a high codimension subset (their closure should just consists of themselves plus maps that factor through a degneration of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$). Your condition that the embedding be homeomorphic to its image is not quite an open condition but it seems more generic than not.

Comment: There are vast number of counterexamples.  For instance, see the following paper for surface subgroups of $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ that are Zariski dense in the entire group: http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~long/pubpdf/CoCompact_IJM.pdf

Comment: Up to conjugation, there only finitely many homomorphisms $SL(2,R)\to G$ (where $G$ is, say, connected and semisimple). At the same time, the dimension of the space of homomorphisms  $\Gamma\to G$, up to conjugation, is $(2p-2)dim(G)$, where $p$ is the genus, provided $p\ge 2$.

Comment: @Tara That’s exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. If you’d like to post that as an answer, then I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homomorphisms from surface groups are very flexible, so there are indeed such examples.

For instance, use: Breuillard–Gelander–Souto–Storm (Dense embeddings of surface groups.
Geom. Topol. 10 (2006), 1373–1389) ([DOI link](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/gt.2006.10.1373))

They proved, for a surface group $\Gamma$ ($\pi_1$ of oriented closed surface of genus $\ge 2$) that, among others, $\Gamma$ embeds densely into arbitrary nontrivial connected semisimple Lie groups.

To deduce a discrete embedding, argue as follows: choose a dense embedding  into $G$ (with $G$ pretty arbitrary, even $G=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ is fine) and consider a standard discrete embedding into $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. Then the diagonal embedding into $G\times\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$ has a Zariski-dense image, so its image is not contained in any copy of any subgroup locally isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})$.

---

Variant, **not** using the above reference [BGSS]:

Choose two Fuchsian embeddings $i_1,i_2:\Gamma\to H$ where $H=\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{R})$, such that the images of $i_1$ and $i_2$ are not conjugate under $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbf{R})$. Then the diagonal embedding $i_1\times i_2:\Gamma\to H\times H$ works (its image is Zariski-dense in $H^2$).

Comment: Sadly, this does not answer the posed question since it is about discrete and faithful representation (an embedding in question is required to be a homeomorphism to its image).

Comment: @MoisheKohan indeed, right... the word "discrete" is indeed useful to emphasize. I'm leaving the (cw) answer anyway; hopefully the discrete example in the comment will be posted too. I tend not to read (or read too quickly) a definition of a term if I'm already familiar with the term, so can miss an unusual additional assumption.

Comment: @MoisheKohan oh, it's straightforward to deduce discrete embeddings too: I added the missing argument.

Comment: Yes, it is correct now. The stronger result however is that every semisimple Lie group without compact factors and of dimension $>3$ contains a discrete subgroup isomorphic to a surface group and not contained in any subgroup locally isomorphic to $SL(2,R)$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan sure it's not the best result (probably it's even true with "Zariski dense"). I was rather looking at the easiest approach. Note that the very elementary argument I give at the end carries over all $G$ containing a subgroup locally isomorphic to $\mathrm{SL}_2\times\mathrm{SL}_2$ (this covers $SL_4$ and $Sp_4$ but not $SL_3$ or rank one groups). Also one of the most important and studied examples is that of quasi-Fuchsian groups.